# JavaScript - building an object of sophisticated data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a function to "memorize data" from a table. The function signature (in AngularJS) is

```
$scope.memoryTable = {};
$scope.memorize = function(name, category, value) {
     if (typeof name !== 'undefined' && typeof category !== 'undefined' && typeof value !== 'undefined') {

          // build data to $scope.memoryTable

     }
}
```

This `memorise` function is called every time the view evaluate a cell data from a table, and add that value to `$scope.memoryTable`

Now, what I want to achieve is to build an array follow this structure:

```
{
  "$name": {
    "$category": "$value"
  }
}
```

For example:

```
> memorize("David", "animal", "cat");
> memorize("David", "book", "fiction");
> memorize("Thomas", "animal", "dog");
```

Will yield

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.memoryTable));

{
  "David": {
    "animal": "cat",
    "book": "fiction"
  },
  "Thomas": {
    "animal": "dog",
  }
}
```

How should I write the code to construct that data table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're not using arrays, you're actually using Plain Old JavaScript Objects.

```
$scope.memoryTable = {};
$scope.memorize = function(name, category, value) {
    if (typeof name !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof category !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof value !== 'undefined') {
        // build data to $scope.memoryTable
        // First, make sure there is an entry for name.
        $scope.memoryTable[name] = $scope.memoryTable[name] || {};
        // Then, set the value for category under that name.
        $scope.memoryTable[name][category] = value;
    }
}
```